# Can't use ORDER BY when SELECTing from a view in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, view

I have a view and while I can execute this statement without any error:

```
SELECT * from vwShippingNoticeBase
order by InvoiceNum
```

when I try to make a stored procedure out of this exact same statement, I get an error:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[upSELECT_shippingNoticeOrderByInvoiceNum]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * FROM vwShippingNoticeBase
order by invoiceNum
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure upSELECT_shippingNoticeByDateRange, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near 'invoiceNum'.

Very strange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding an `END` to your stored procedure ....

```
CREAT PROCEDURE [dbo].[upSELECT_shippingNoticeOrderByInvoiceNum]
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT * FROM vwShippingNoticeBase
   ORDER BY invoiceNum
END   -- <<<==== you're missing the END for the BEGIN you have!
```

Comment: oh jesus. Thanks! I had commented out some lines and didn't move my END back up to the top. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MaxHodges: given enough eyeballs, all errors become shallow :-)

Comment: given slightly more informative error messages, all errors before shallow ;)

Comment: @MaxHodges: well - the message is absolutely 100% spot on - your syntax is invalid, near `InvoiceNum` - you're missing an `END` :-) Writing **good** error messages is even more of an art than programming itself....